# Cleaning Up DNS: Getting all forward-resolution records for a given IP

Tags: powershell, dns

Our enterprise network DNS is filthy; we know we have tombstones all over the place, and scavenging was never turned on. Our systems administrators tried turning on scavenging, and it brought the entire network to its knees. So, we have to clean up manually before turning on scavenging. (Please do not comment on the scavenging issue or our administrators' competence or lack thereof; we are having *that* discussion internally.)

For statistical reasons (and to present the issue to the Right People in the Right Way), we want to find all the DNS forward-resolution records that resolve to a given IP address. We're working with PowerShell 4 or 5 on Windows computers. `[System.Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry()` uses the reverse lookup if we pass it an IP address; we're not going to find the duplicate IP addresses that way. So, how can we find forward records that resolve to a given IP address, knowing only the address that we want the records to resolve to?

Comment: Doing reverse lookups with the forward lookup table isn't possible with DNS commands. You will need to enumerate your forward lookup zones and then dump the zone table and do the lookups yourself. The DnsServer module included with Windows Server 2012 can be used to accomplish this: https://serverfault.com/a/556168/77656 Note that you probably need to be a DNS admin to do this.

Comment: @BaconBitsn - That's going to be impossibly painful; we only have one zone with all 10,000-odd workstations in it.

Comment: I didn't say you had to do the lookups *by hand*. You'll just need to process the output of `Get-DnsServerResourceRecord`.

Comment: You could get all duplicated with something like: `Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName $ZoneName | Where-Object RecordType -eq 'A' | Group-Object -Property RecordData | Where-Object Count -gt 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group`. I've no idea if that's correct because it's been about 5 years since I've had DNS admin, and it's going to be *painfully* slow because you're using a version of Powershell where Group-Object performed terribly, but I believe that works.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - Export/dump your zone to file. Find duplicates via tool/method of your choice. Put final format in Excel to sort/present in the Right Way.

Comment: @BaconBits - My concern is that trying to pull "bulk data" from that single zone is going to bring the system to its knees unless there's some way of rate-limiting the pull.

Comment: @Orangutech - See my comment to BaconBits regarding pulling bulk data.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Microsoft's DNS Server implementation isn't held together by duct tape, you can do a zone import without "bringing the system to its knees": `Export-DnsServerZone [zone name] -FileName [zone name].zone`